# Is it possible to use Bluetooth serial and BLE client simultaneously in ESP32?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, esp32

Is it possible to use classic Bluetooth and BLE at same time in esp32 with Arduino ?

IDE - Arduino ide

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to [this](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/1150) GitHub issue it is possible to use classic Bluetooth and BLE together.

GitHub user [@beegee-tokyo](https://github.com/beegee-tokyo) who raised that issue suggests to initialize the Bluetooth and BLE services in the following manner :-

`Init BLE device => BLEDevice::init(apName);
 Init Bluetooth Serial => SerialBT.begin(apName);
 Then do the rest of the BLE initialisation like
  - create server
  - add callbacks to server
  - add characteristics
  - start server
  - start advertising`

He has also posted his finding on his [blog](http://desire.giesecke.tk/index.php/2018/02/27/esp32-bluetooth-serial-and-ble-server-running-together/) and [wiki](http://desire.giesecke.tk/index.php/2018/02/27/initialize-bluetooth-serial-and-ble-server/) and has also shared the following code snippet :-

```
// Initialize BLE
BLEDevice::init(apName);
BLEDevice::setPower(ESP_PWR_LVL_P7);

if (!SerialBT.begin(apName)) {
    sendDebug(debugLabel, errorLabel + digitalTimeDisplaySec() + " Failed to start BTSerial", false);
}

// Create BLE Server
pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();

// Set server callbacks
pServer->setCallbacks(new MyServerCallbacks());

// Create BLE Service
pService = pServer->createService(BLEUUID((uint16_t)SERVICE_UUID),20);

// Create BLE Characteristic for Alert
pCharacteristicNotify = pService->createCharacteristic(
    BLEUUID((uint16_t)NOTIFICATION_UUID),
    BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ     |
    // BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_INDICATE |
    BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY
);

// add other characteristics

// Start the service
pService->start();

// Start advertising
pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();

pAdvertising->start();
```